# Using ActiveAdmin I need to show the payment balance a student has (on the student index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, activeadmin

This is my current hurdle:
I have 3 related models: Student, Course and Payment. They are related as follows:

- Student & Course (student belongs_to course)
- Payments & Student (payments belong_to student)

The models have the following attributes:

- Student(:name, :course_id)
- Course(:name, :course_cost)
- Payment(:payment_date, :student_id, :payment_amount)

I'm using ActiveAdmin and trying to show the balance a student has (i.e. course_cost - payment_amount) as a column "Balance" on the index of Student. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't directly related to ActiveAdmin.
You can define method in Student class, which returns balance for current student:

```
def balance
  self.course.course_cost - self.payments.collect(&:payment_amount).sum
end
```

And display balance in index:

```
index do
  column :balance
end
```